# Docker how to pass a relative path as an argument

Tags: docker

I would like to run this command:

```
docker run docker-mup deploy --config .deploy/mup.js
```

where `docker-mup` is the name the image, and `deploy`, `--config`, `.deploy/mup.js` are arguments

My question: how to mount a volume such that `.deploy/mup.js` is understood as the relative path on the host from where the `docker run` command is run?

I tried different things with `VOLUME` but it seems that VOLUME does the contrary: it exposes a container directory to the host.

I can't use -v because this container will be used as a build step in a CI/CD pipeline and as I understand it, it is just run as is.

Answer (score 48):

> I can't use -v because this container will be used as a build step in a CI/CD pipeline and as I understand it, it is just run as is.

Using `-v` to expose your current directory is the only way to make that `.deploy/mup.js` file inside your container, unless you are baking it into the image itself using a `COPY` directive in your `Dockerfile`.

Using the `-v` option to map a host directory might look something like this:

```
docker run \
  -v $PWD/.deploy:/data/.deploy \
  -w /data \
  docker-mup deploy --config .deploy/mup.js
```

This would map (using `-v ...`) the `$PWD/.deploy` directory onto `/data/.deploy` in your container, set the current working directory to `/data` (using `-w ...`), and then run `deploy --config .deploy/mup.js`.

Comment: It worked on my MacOS. For Windows, we have to use `%cd%` instead of `$PWD`.

Comment: Sure, but why execute another process when you can just use a variable?

Answer (score 11):

#### Windows - Powershell

If you're **inside** the directory you want to bind mount, use `${pwd}`:

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web -v ${pwd}:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

or `$pwd/.` (forward slash dot):

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web -v $pwd/.:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

Just `$pwd` will cause an error:

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web -v $pwd:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx

Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to
delimit the name
```

Mounting a subdirectory underneath your current location, e.g. "`site-content`", `$pwd/` + `subdir` is fine:

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web -v $pwd/site-content:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution also works in bash in linux.

Comment: I was wrong a bit. `$PWD` should be uppercase in linux otherwise you mount `/somedir` instead of `./somedir`

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was no need for `$pwd`, and using the standard current folder notation `.` was enough. For reference, I used `docker-compose.yml` and ran `docker-compose up`.

Here is a relevant part of `docker-compose.yml`.

```
volumes:
    - '.\logs\:/data'
```